# Velostrata cloud migration is getting failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, migration, runbook

I am trying migrate simple windows EC2 instance from AWS to GCP. I have set up everything successfully followed from GCP docs.

I tried with full migration but migration got failed after 10-15% showing error that `"failed to create storage bucket"`.

I have checked all the aspects from aws as well from google side but not getting any clue. If somebody faced same issue and resolved it, please share how to overcome this error.

Snapshot of the error message is also attached for the reference.

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot ? Or better error message in text format ?

Comment: I did attached snap while posting the question but something must have gone wrong. It is not visible here. I am not aware how to attache snapshot in comment section so please find below error statement.

"[Failed to create storage bucket,connecting to importer, io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: Unavailable: No destination service , '10.0.0.246-9124'] (Sub-task failed)"

Comment: I can't see any error message in your comment - please edit your original post and put it there (in text format).

Comment: [Failed to create storage bucket,connecting to importer, io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: Unavailable: No destination service , '10.0.0.246-9124'] (Sub-task failed)"

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how are you doing the migration (list of steps) I can't find anything concrete based on the error you pasted - but need more detailes to troubleshoot...

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your response. I have below followed below steps.

1. Established the VPC tunnel between AWS and GCP. As I am doing this only for testing purpose I have kept all ports open and all traffic allowed from both AWS as well as GCP end.
2. Created the group in aws vpc having necessary roles,policies, permissions and access. This group is created using cloud formation template which is provided in GCP document. Then I created the new user assigned to the this newly created group.

Comment: This user's secrete key and access key is useful while configuring user credentials-the source cloud in velostrata manager console
3. I assigned necessary roles mesntioned in gcp doc to myself. Created Service accounts use to configure the velostrata and assigned the mentioned roles to that service accounts.
4. Configured velostrata successfully as instructed in the GCP documents.
5. Extensions also configured in velstrata. Node A and B created after that. Source cloud  configured.
6. Runbook is updated in migration waves and validation is also passed of the runbook.

Comment: 7. Created new wave and started full migration. Velostrata Importer - i-02b138b0adfd820f4 vm created at aws end.
8. Migration started and then failed after reaching and 10-15 %

Some Logs are as follows

2020-06-22 11:05:20 WARN JobsRunnerImpl Failed: [i-02b138b0adfd820f4], Blocking: []